# SQL query IF statement in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, if-statement

What is the proper and efficient way of making the condition in the given query?

Yes it's working, but I want the query to be more efficient, example what if there's a lot of strings to be validated with `@CORP`.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_EditProfile]
    @CORP AS VARCHAR(100)
AS
BEGIN
    IF((@CORP = 'something') OR (@CORP = 'somethingElse')) //CONDITION
    BEGIN
    END
END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `IN` statement, that will save you some characters of typing:

```
IF @CORP IN ('something', 'somethingElse')
BEGIN
    -- your code
END
```

Comment: oh, i thought this only works on where clause. Thanks!

Comment: I'm new to most of sql, and would love to know what the '@' character is used for. Is it like the $ variable in php to create a variable (hence making @CORP a variable in SQL) or is it something completely different?

Comment: @Webeng Yes, it is variable, and in SQL Server variables first character must be `@`. See https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187953(v=sql.105).aspx